# Why won't onclick event fire after setting new model to a grid with buttons?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, zk

I have a grid with 2 buttons on each row, for edition and deletion. When I set a new model to the grid, the buttons won't fire the onClick event so I can handle it in the composer. I don't wanna bother using the MVVM pattern, I want to use the MVC pattern. I want to know how to make the buttons function after setting a new model to the grid.

Here is my ZUL File:

```xml
<?page title="ZK Application" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>
<window id="win" title="new page title" border="normal" apply="com.example.zk.controllers.ActorController">
<intbox id="txtActorId" visible="false" value="-1"></intbox>
<label value="First Name"></label><textbox id="txtFirstName"></textbox>
<label value="Last Name"></label><textbox id="txtLastName"></textbox>
<button id="btnSave" label="Save"/>
<button id="btnClear" label="Clear" />
<button id="btnDeleteAll" label="Delete All"/>

<grid id="grdActors" model="${win$composer.actorsModel }">
    <columns>
        <column label="ID" />
        <column label="First Name" />
        <column label="Last Name" />
        <column/>
    </columns>
    <template name="model" var="actor">
        <row value="valor${each.actorId }">
            <label value="${each.actorId }" />
            <label value="${each.firstName }" />
            <label value="${each.lastName }" />
            <button id="btnEdit${each.actorId }" label="Edit" >
                <custom-attributes actor="${each }" action="edit"/>
            </button>
            <button id="btnDelete${each.actorId }" label="Delete">
                <custom-attributes actor="${each }" action="delete"/>
            </button>
        </row>
    </template>
</grid>

</window>
</zk>
```

Here is my composer:

```
package com.example.zk.controllers;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Event;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.SelectorComposer;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.Listen;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.VariableResolver;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.Wire;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.WireVariable;
import org.zkoss.zul.Combobox;
import org.zkoss.zul.Grid;
import org.zkoss.zul.Intbox;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListModel;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListModelList;
import org.zkoss.zul.Messagebox;
import org.zkoss.zul.Textbox;

import com.example.zk.dao.ActorDAO;
import com.example.zk.entities.Actor;

@VariableResolver(org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver.class)
public class ActorController extends SelectorComposer<Component> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @WireVariable("actorDao")
    ActorDAO dao;

    @Wire
    Textbox textBox;

    @Wire
    Combobox cbxActors;

    @Wire
    Textbox txtFirstName;

    @Wire
    Textbox txtLastName;

    @Wire
    Intbox txtActorId;

    @Wire
    Grid grdActors;

    public List<Actor> getActors(){
        return dao.getAllActors();
    }

    public ListModel<Actor> getActorsModel(){
        return new ListModelList<>(getActors());
    }   

    @Listen("onClick=#btnSave")
    public void saveActor(){
        Actor actor = new Actor((short) txtActorId.getValue().intValue(), txtFirstName.getValue(), txtLastName.getValue(), new Date());
        dao.saveActor(actor);
        refreshGrid();
        clearAll();
    }

    @Listen("onClick=#grdActors button")
    public void editActor(Event event){
        Actor actor = (Actor) event.getTarget().getAttribute("actor");
        if(((String) event.getTarget().getAttribute("action")).equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
            deleteActor(actor);
            return;
        }
        txtActorId.setValue((int)actor.getActorId());
        txtFirstName.setValue(actor.getFirstName());
        txtLastName.setValue(actor.getLastName());
    }

    public void deleteActor(Actor actor){
//      Actor actor = (Actor) event.getTarget().getAttribute("actor");
        dao.delete(actor);
        refreshGrid();
    }

    @Listen("onClick=#btnDeleteAll")
    public void deletaAll(){
        dao.deleteAll();
        refreshGrid();
    }

    @Listen("onClick=#btnClear")
    public void clearAll(){
        txtActorId.setValue(0);
        txtFirstName.setValue("");
        txtLastName.setValue("");
    }

    public void refreshGrid(){
        grdActors.setModel(getActorsModel());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, all event listeners are attached to model in MVC frameworks.

So if you replace the model, the listeners would still work in case of changes in old model.

You have to set all listeners again for the new model (and remove them from old model (which is done by framework in most cases)) to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your component (`Window`) is already created at the time you change the model. So zk don't call [`doAfterCompose`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/7.0.3/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/select/SelectorComposer.html#doAfterCompose%28T%29) and won't wire the components/event listners.

What should work, is fire the `onCreate` event of the `Window` in the constructor of the model (not tested)

```
Events.postEvent("onCreate", getSelf, null);
```

But it is bad practice in my opinion.
More correct would be, to manipulate the model.